# interpretation of deviance in logistic model

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, deviance

In logistic regression model for binary data,

If the residual deviance(2*(likelihood of saturated model-likelihood of my model)) is 56.728 with df=117, what can I say about the lack of fit of the model?

I don't know whether the deviance should be small, or similar to the degree of freedom when the model fits well.

Comment: The deviance is interpreted in comparison to the null (intercept-only) model. ¿What is the deviance of the null model for your dependent variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deviance is a model's goodness-of-fit statistic.

You first need to fit the null model. The difference between the deviances for the null model and your model follows an approximate chi-squared distribution with k-degrees of freedom(df).
(k is the difference of dfs between two models.)

For example,

your model deviance (df) = 56.728 (117)

null model deviacne (df) = 70 (120)

=> 70-56.728=13.272 ~ chi_squred (3)

and then you can test the significance of your model.